# Conditional element replacement using cellfun

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array, function-handle, elementwise-operations

```
vec = randi(10,10,1)
vec(vec < 5) = 0

func = @(x) x(x < 5) = 0    % This isn't valid
```

How am I supposed to translate the second line of code into a function handle that I can use in conjunction with `cellfun`?

Comment: Do the different vectors have different sizes? In case the size is the same (i.e. they're just stored as a cell for convenience), and assuming their total size is not too large in terms of memory - the cell array can be converted to a numeric matrix, the substitution performed, then the numeric matrix converted back to a cell array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use multiplication, since if your condition is satisfied you have `1` and `0` otherwise.

Multiplying by the inverse of the condition therefore gives you either an unchanged value (if condition is not satisfied) or your desired substitution of `0`!

```
func = @(x) x .* (~(x < 5)) % Replace values less than 5 with 0
```

If you had a different substitution, you could expand the same logic

```
func = @(x) x .* (~(x < 5)) + 10 * (x < 5) % replace values less than 5 with 10
```

Comment: @Dev-iL I left the condition as `~(x<5)` instead of `x>=5` to show that you need to negate *whatever condition* you're using, assuming `x<5` is a simplification in the question! Sticking `~` in front means you don't have to think through the logical negation for more complex statements. Of course in this case the two are equivalent...

Comment: This seems to be a suitable solution. One question: Am I correct in saying that the equal sign (=) won't work in anonymous functions?

Comment: @Andi Please see my above comment about using `~`, it is the logical negation ("not") of the condition, i.e. `~true==false`. You are correct that you can't use `=` within anonymous functions. The only way around this is when setting properties of handle objects when you can use the `set` command instead of an `=` statement, however that doesn't apply for matrixes like this example.

Answer (score 2):

How about not using an anonymous function, but a function handle instead?

```
vec = randi(10,10,1);
vec_cell = num2cell(vec);
vec_cell_out = cellfun(@func, vec_cell);

function x = func(x)
    x(x<5) = 0;
end
```

Comment: Yes, a function handle is working. However, in my view this one-liner screams for an anonymous function.